# How to embed an autoplaying YouTube video in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to embed the new iframe version of a YouTube video and get it to auto play.

As far as I can tell, there is no way of doing this by amending flags to the URL. Is there a way to do it by using JavaScript & the API?

Comment: Is there a way to mute the sound when the video starts playing, through code, I don't want to surprise my users with sound

Comment: Browser has settings for that

Answer (score 466, accepted):

This works in Chrome but not Firefox 3.6 (warning: RickRoll video):

```
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The [JavaScript API for iframe embeds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) exists, but is still posted as an experimental feature.

UPDATE: The iframe API is now fully supported and ["Creating YT.Player objects - Example 2"](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Example_Video_Player_Constructors) shows how to set "autoplay" in JavaScript.

Comment: Hint: On mobile devices it's possible both the src parameter and the api call will not work due to restrictions: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Mobile_considerations

Comment: I find that on mobile (Webview on Android 5.0) the function `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` isn't triggered. Anyone have a solution ?

Comment: Is there a way to mute the sound when the video starts playing, through code, I don't want to surprise my users with sound

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48086769/youtube-iframe-api-allow-autoplay-chrome-65 @JoJo

Comment: You may also need: allow="autoplay" for your iFrame

Comment: @danielmetlitski You can use muted attributes so you can mute your video

Answer (score 76):

Since April 2018, Google made some changes to the [Autoplay Policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes). You not only need to add the `autoplay=1` as a query param, but also add `allow='autoplay'` as an iframe's attribute

So you will have to do something like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?autoplay=1" allow='autoplay'></iframe>
```

Comment: autoplay=1 as paramter is not enough (time of writing July 20). I'd to add allow='autoplay'  to the iframe to get the autoplay feature working.

Comment: @Gkiokan Yep, u need that. I had that in the snippet :)

Comment: Yea, I wanted to make it clear to the others that the solution is not only the param in the URL but also the extra parameter :) Maybe you should mention that explicit.

Comment: You may also need to set "&mute=1", that's what I needed as well.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40685142/youtube-autoplay-does-not-work-with-iframe

Answer (score 58):

August 2018 I didn't find a working example on the iframe implementation.
Other questions were related to Chrome only, which gave it away a little.

You'll have to mute sound `mute=1` in order to autoplay on Chrome. FF and IE seem to be working just fine using `autoplay=1` as parameter.

```
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/{{YOUTUBE-ID}}?autoplay=1&mute=1" name="youtube embed" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Most helpful answer by far. Makes sense.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, but how could I unmute the video after autoplaying it?

Comment: The point is it's impossible programmatically for embedded videos. To unmute, a user increases the volume on his player. At that point his consent is given to even play audio.

Comment: This is not even in the official docs: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#autoplay

Comment: It's a browser related thing, not a youtube thing:
https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/

Comment: Needed this. The [selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7286526/18620006) wasn't working in my chrome development environment. This should be the selected one, as it will work in any browser

Comment: Confirmed Chrome 107.0.5304.88 requires `mute=1` param to autoplay.

Answer (score 41):

The embedded code of youtube has autoplay off by default. Simply add `autoplay=1`at the end of "src" attribute. For example:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xzvScRnF6MU?autoplay=1" width="960" height="447" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: add `?autoplay=1` to the src

Comment: yes actually autoplay=1  while ? indicate src may have parameters like color, controls and each separated by & sign. detail description can be seen here
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters

Answer (score 13):

2014 iframe embed on how to embed a youtube video with autoplay and no suggested videos at end of clip

```
rel=0&amp;autoplay
```

Example Below: .

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/JWgp7Ny3bOo?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 12):

at the end of the iframe src, add `&enablejsapi=1` to allow the js API to be used on the video

and then with jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
  $('.video-selector iframe')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"playVideo","args":""}', '*');
});
```

this should play the video automatically on document.ready

note, that you could also use this inside a click function to click on another element to start the video

More importantly, you cannot auto-start videos on a mobile device so users will always have to click on the video-player itself to start the video

Edit:
I'm actually not 100% sure on document.ready the iframe will be ready, because YouTube could still be loading the video. I'm actually using this function inside a click function:

```
$('.video-container').on('click', function(){
  $('video-selector iframe')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"playVideo","args":""}', '*');
  // add other code here to swap a custom image, etc
});
```

Comment: Utilizing this answer, and wrapping the jQuery selector in a `setTimeout` worked for me.

Comment: Same here, just fire the event several times every second and it will work.

Comment: It is not about firing the event frequently!
YouTube had recently updated their policy on auto playing embedded videos. The new policy is that a video CANNOT be auto played until there is a real user interaction on the page (clicking, scrolling...). I think that in your case since you're firing the code every second, the code just run normally after the first user interaction, so you'd think that the reason is the frequent firing of the event! Nevertheless, it is NOT a good practice to fire a code like this every second!

Answer (score 6):

The *flags*, or parameters that you can use with IFRAME and OBJECT embeds are documented here; the details about which parameter works with what player are also clearly mentioned:

[YouTube Embedded Players and Player Parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)

You will notice that `autoplay` is supported by all players (AS3, AS2 and HTML5).

Answer (score 6):

Multiple queries tip for those who don't know (past me and future me)

If you're making a single query with the url just `?autoplay=1` works [as shown by mjhm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7286526/3377049)

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0?autoplay=1"></iframe>
```

If you're making multiple queries remember the first one begins with a `?` while the rest begin with a `&`

Say you want to turn off related videos but enable autoplay...

This works

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0?rel=0&autoplay=1"></iframe>
```

and this works

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0?autoplay=1&rel=0"></iframe>
```

But these won't work..

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0?rel=0?autoplay=1"></iframe>

<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0&autoplay=1&rel=0"></iframe>
```

**example comparisons**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/p4dpo5y4/

**more info**

Read NextLocal's reply below for more info about using multiple query strings

Comment: The reason yours didn't work is because you already had `?rel=0` in there. If you removed that it would have worked. Read more about query string syntax [here](http://wiki.marketruler.com/Query_string#Query_String) if you'd like. `?rel=0?autoplay=1` should be either `?autoplay=1` or `?rel=0&autoplay=1`

Comment: @NextLocal Thanks, I'll come back to this and edit/delete my answer next time I'm working on something that iframes youtube videos.

Comment: the example you're providing `http://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0&autoplay=1` definitely won't work, but `https://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0?autoplay=1` should

Comment: @NextLocal Ha, I got it now. Not sure how I didn't realize that :D Thanks again.

Comment: Is there a way to mute the sound when the video starts playing, through code, I don't want to surprise my users with sound

Comment: @danielmetlitski I'm sure you've figured how to mute by now but here's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44725609/3377049)  future readers

Answer (score 4):

To have the accepted answer by mjhm working on Chrome 66 in May 2018, I added `allow=autoplay` to the iframe and `enable_js=1` to the query string:

```
<iframe allow=autoplay width="420px" height="345px" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0?autoplay=1&enable_js=1"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays I include a new attribute "allow" on iframe tag, for example:

> allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope;
>   picture-in-picture"

The final code is:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/[VIDEO-CODE]?autoplay=1" 
frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"></iframe>
```

Comment: works a trick! I couldn't figure out why page loads were only showing the video sometimes and not other times !

Comment: Have all that but still not working :(

Answer (score 4):

This is the perfect solution if someone is looking for, **autoplay*** is the key here, which is not mentioned anywhere.

```
  <iframe allow="autoplay *; fullscreen *" allowfullscreen="true" 
      src="https://example.com">
   </iframe>
```

& if you want to lazy load the youtube video completely use this-

```
  <iframe
        srcdoc="<style>*{padding:0;margin:0;overflow:hidden}html,body{height:100%}img,span{position:absolute;width:100%;top:0;bottom:0;margin:auto}span{height:1.5em;text-align:center;font:48px/1.5 sans-serif;color:white;text-shadow:0 0 0.5em black}</style><a href=https://www.youtube.com/embed/unICbsPGFIA?autoplay=1><img src=https://img.youtube.com/vi/zEkgWzi5T-Y/hqdefault.jpg><span>▶</span></a>"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/unICbsPGFIA?autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=zEkgWzi5T-Y"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay *; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
        allowfullscreen
      ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

1 - add `&enablejsapi=1` to `IFRAME SRC`

2 - jQuery func:

```
  $('iframe#your_video')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"playVideo","args":""}', '*');
```

Works fine

Comment: In my case it works from the console, or when I already interacted with the video manually. Doesn't work on load, even timed-out

Answer (score 0):

To use javascript api,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
  <div id="ytapiplayer">
    You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
    var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
    swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/OyHoZhLdgYw?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3",
                       "ytapiplayer", "425", "356", "8", null, null, params, atts);

  </script>
```

To play the youtube with the id:

```
swfobject.embedSWF
```

reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference[magazine](http://note.taable.com)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" 
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9IILMHo4RCQ?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1" 
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score -1):

December 2018,

Looking for an AUTOPLAY, LOOP, MUTE youtube video for react.

Other answers didn't worked.

I found a solution with a library: [react-youtube](https://github.com/troybetz/react-youtube)

```
class Video extends Component {

    _onReady(event) {
        // add mute
        event.target.mute();
        // add autoplay
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    render() {
        const opts = {
            width: '100%',
            height: '700px',
            playerVars: {
                // remove video controls 
                controls: 0,
                // remove related video
                rel: 0
            }
        };

        return (
            <YouTube
                videoId="oHg5SJYRHA0"
                opts={opts}
                // add autoplay
                onReady={this._onReady}
                // add loop
                onEnd={this._onReady}
            />
        )
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can embed an auto-playing YouTube video with an Iframe tag as per [Google's autoplay Iframe policy](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/#iframe-delegation)

Try this way:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video-id" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen"></iframe>
```

While this process is only applicable for one video at a time, to embed a collection of YouTube videos using an Iframe code, you need to use a third-party tool like Taggbox Widget, which is integrated with Google's API that allows users to embed YouTube videos, shorts using channel & playlist URLs in the form of a [YouTube widget](https://taggbox.com/youtube-widget/).

Furthermore, you can easily embed that responsive YouTube widget on your website with the generated Iframe code.

```
<iframe src="https://widget.taggbox.com/unique-id" style="width:100%;height:600px;border:none;"></iframe>
```