# YouTube autoplay not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube, autoplay

For a while now I have been using this script, where the video is automatically playing full-screen. For now suddenly the video doesn't play automatically in Chrome. But in Firefox and Edge it still works.

So maybe Google changed settings? Does anyone know how to fix this, please?
You see the live example here: [www.brunomazereel.com](http://www.brunomazereel.com/)

```
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
    playerVars: {
        'autoplay': 1,
        'controls': 0,
        'autohide': 1,
        'wmode': 'opaque',
        'showinfo': 0,
        'loop': 1,
        'rel': 0,
        'playlist': 'rh5QiehIlVA,Bl63bdR-Ko0,'
        },
    videoId: 'u-cjliof1xk',
    events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
});
}
function onPlayerReady(event) {
event.target();
$('#text').fadeIn(400);
}
$(window).scroll(function() {
var hT = $('.m-video').height(),
   wS = $(this).scrollTop();
if (wS > hT) {
  player.pauseVideo();
}
else {
  player.playVideo();
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Apparently, [Google did block autoplay](https://www.theverge.com/2018/5/3/17251104/google-chrome-66-autoplay-sound-videos-mute). Since it's built-in, I doubt there is a fix for that

Comment: I see few errors at "event.target()" in the method  "onPlayerReady". Although it might not be related ,by worth taking a look. Check the chrome console.

Answer (score 27):

(One) of the possible solution taken from the comments discussion would be **muting the video** if sound isn't that important in your case *(if it is, I'll leave the answer as it could help other people)*.

It's apparently the only way to have autoplay **always** enabled. From the article :

> "Muted autoplay is always allowed."

Source : [Google changelog](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

---

Simply add in your playerVars:

```
mute : 1
```

[Source for the muted video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35044594/youtube-how-to-present-embed-video-with-sound-muted/41045251#41045251)

Comment: About how to set youtube iframe mute: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35044594/youtube-how-to-present-embed-video-with-sound-muted

Answer (score 12):

You should put the `allow="autoplay"` on the embedding `iframe` element

```
<!-- Autoplay is allowed. -->
<iframe src="https://cross-origin.com/myvideo.html" allow="autoplay">

<!-- Autoplay and Fullscreen are allowed. -->
<iframe src="https://cross-origin.com/myvideo.html" allow="autoplay; fullscreen">
```

Chrome's [autoplay policies](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) :

> - Top frames can [delegate autoplay permission](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#iframe) to their `iframe`s to allow `autoplay` **with sound**.
> - **Muted** autoplay is always allowed.
> - Autoplay **with sound** is allowed if:
>
>   - User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
>   - On desktop, the user's [Media Engagement Index](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#mei) threshold has been crossed, meaning the user has previously play video with sound.
>   - On mobile, the user has added the site to their home screen.

Answer (score 8):

Google chrome removed the autoplay functionality. See below:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: "Muted autoplay is always allowed", might be worth something

Comment: Chrome's autoplay policies are simple:

1)Muted autoplay is always allowed.
2)Autoplay with sound is allowed if:
 User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning the user has previously play video with sound.
On mobile, the user has added the site to his or her home screen.
Top frames can delegate autoplay permission to their iframes to allow autoplay with sound.

Answer (score 0):

for me worked this solution:

```
jQuery("video-iframe")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
```

It doesn't played for me even with all valid autoplay html attributes, but above code helped.