# Hide Youtube title and logo ( on right bottom ) on an embed

Tags: youtube

> **Goal :-** Wants to hide logo and title both together.

I want to hide title and logo both together using youtube embaded.

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/w5C7S0FlSyM?&modestbranding=1&showtitle=0&controls=0" frameborder="0"width="500" height="280"></iframe>
```

It shows

[image]

In above screenshot it shows title where i have set `modestbranding=1` which means this parameter let me use a YouTube player that does not show a YouTube logo.

if i remove `modestbranding=1` and set `&showinfo=0` than it starts showing youtube logo at bottom right.

[image]

Now if i do `&showinfo=1` it hides the **youtube** logo at right end corner but start showing title.

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/w5C7S0FlSyM?&showinfo=1&showtitle=0&controls=0"frameborder="0"width="300"height="200</iframe>
```

[image]

I want to hide both **title** as well as **Youtube logo** at bottom right.

How can i do that ?

Any help ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're embedding video from YouTube then you should give credit to it, you should not hide YouTube logo and it won't let you hide it. fugga
;)

Comment: previously they were giving a parameters to hide the YouTube logo than it got deprecated.I got a good option https://plyr.io/ where logo title will be as it is but they will not be clickable ...  MC!

Comment: @MayurChauhan yeah, except it's my video. It's supposed to be muted and autoplay on our site, which is an extremely common use-case.

Comment: @ChrisRock you can do that with YT embeds. See this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35044759/4819200

Answer (score 1):

This use to be controlled by the `showinfo` parameter, but it appears to now be deprecated with no replacement. https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?playerVersion=HTML5#showinfo

I'm also looking for a way to hide this.

Comment: As far as I know, as of sept 2018 it's not possible anymore.

Comment: previously they were giving a parameters to hide the YouTube logo than it got deprecated.I got a good option plyr.io where logo title will be as it is but they will not be clickable