# How to alter YouTube url to unmute video played on android device (Edit: Already Solved)

Tags: javascript, android, web, url, youtube

When I click on a YouTube
url, eg:

*url:`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1AwAy_RebQ`*

The video starts off already playing but muted,is there a way to **alter or the url** or possibly jsinjection

eg:`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1AwAy_RebQ&muted=1`

I've gone through the questions and answers on this platform but the methods are either deprecated or don't offer a clear cut answer.

Comment: It won't work. Probably you have to write a function to achieve that functionality

Comment: @AbhishekDutt suppose I use a javascript injection what function would I call to unmute?

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35044594/youtube-how-to-present-embed-video-with-sound-muted) helps

Comment: @AbhishekDutt Most of them are deprecated and I'm not using iframe tags but instead only load url or maybe can try jsinjection