# jQuery play iframe embedded YouTube video on page load

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to auto play Iframe embedded youtube video on page or document load not any click event.

I have tried following ways but it does not play in chrome & mobile device.

`<iframe width="800" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/W0LHTWG-UmQ?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Second Way

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#playvideo').click(function(ev) {
  
  jQuery("#video_played")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
    ev.preventDefault();
  });
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('#playvideo').trigger('click');
  }, 4000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="video_played" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/W0LHTWG-UmQ?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&loop=1&playlist=W0LHTWG-UmQ&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<a rel="wp-video-lightbox"  style="display: none;" href="#" id="playvideo">Play video</a>
```

I only want to play youtube embedded video during load page not any clicking event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [YouTube Iframe embed auto play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281765/youtube-iframe-embed-auto-play)

Comment: It's not duplicate i want autoplay during load page & i faced issue in chrome browser & mobile devices , I also tried my custom js script that i have mentioned above.

Comment: change `?autoplay=1` to `?rel=0&autoplay=1`

Comment: @GovindSamrow already that answer added in question , and he mentioned its not working :p

Comment: Have you tried moving `jQuery("#video_played")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";` out of the click event?

Comment: @LewisBrowne , yes i have tried that way also but it's not work.

Comment: @Shiladitya that code is not working in responsive in mobile.

Answer (score 3):

Wont autoplay on chrome unless you add mute to video.
mute=1

Comment: where? can you provide an example?

Comment: @Wallen. Here is an example: of the `mute=1` parameter: `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pTBjHjRhx_Y?autoplay=1&mute=1" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media;" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://codepen.io/Shiladitya/pen/prwJKB

```css
iframe {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<iframe height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Just add `?rel=0&autoplay=1`

Comment: I already tried it but now working in chrome browser & mobile

Comment: May be cache issue.

Comment: `<iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/EnGcluOlCQ0?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>` I tested the code in my local, its working. I changed the `youTube` video

Comment: Not working in Iphone 6, have you checked in responsive.

Comment: Have a look into`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496144/can-you-autoplay-html5-videos-on-the-ipad`

Answer (score 0):

you can add autoplay=1 in the end of the youtube link. please refer below.

```
     <iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ofKxLfdUGnk?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```