# Youtube iframe api allow="autoplay" Chrome 65

Tags: iframe, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

Chrome 65, the current canary version, is blocking iframed youtube videos from auto playing with sound.

The latest changes to Chrome require the iframe to have **allow="autoplay"**

How do I go about adding **allow="autoplay"** to the youtube iframe api? I can't find it in any of the documentation.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#iframe

> A feature policy allows developers to selectively enable and disable use of various browser features and APIs. Once an origin has received autoplay permission, it can delegate that permission to cross-origin iframes with a new feature policy for autoplay. Note that autoplay is allowed by default on same-origin iframes.

```html
<iframe src="myvideo.html" allow="autoplay">
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The YouTube IFrame API has been recently updated to use `allow=autoplay` instead of `gesture=media`. It should now work as expected.

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you the fix is working! Are there plans to support Safari 11 as well?

Comment: It doesn't seems to work anymore, somehow it's not working for me, with both `allow=autoplay` and `gesture=media`, on Chome Mac Version 66.0.3359.181

Comment: @SaeeshTendulkar I can't remember since this is pretty old to me. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You just add it in the src URL like:

> [autoplay](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#autoplay)
>
> This parameter specifies whether the initial video will automatically
> start to play when the player loads. Supported values are 0 or 1. The
> default value is 0.

Comment: @nougui  
  
I am creating the player using Javascript and when I add `autoplay:1` it does not add allow="autoplay" to the iframe that gets embedded on my site.  
  
`function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '360',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE'
      autoplay: '1',
    });
  }`