# Can I click into a YouTube iframe using jquery?

Tags: jquery, youtube

I have the following iframe example:

```
<iframe class="iframe-test" id="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/iRYDYrj3Bfw" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I have tried the following but nothing is happening:

```
$('#video').click();
```

Does it have something to do with cross-domain iframes?

Comment: If autoplay is what you want to achieve try to follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281765/youtube-iframe-embed-auto-play

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get DOM elements from a different domain site opened by iframe. Your code would work if you open a site that has the same domain as the origin.