# Force manual click on Youtube iframe using Jquery

Tags: jquery, youtube, click

I need to play the video on "Play" button click on a site

I tried using this code but it doesn't trigger the play on the Youtube Video.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.eg-henryharrison-element-2', function(event) { 
  event.preventDefault(); 
  jQuery(".esg-youtubevideo").click(); 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try adding `autoplay=1` option to your iframe src like this

```
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qYcSef6Mk58?version=3&enablejsapi=1&html5=1&controls=1&autohide=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&fs=1&playsinline=1&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Here is a related question already been asked at stack overflow:
[YouTube Iframe embed auto play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281765/youtube-iframe-embed-auto-play)

Comment: Hi Goldy, Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I'm not asking about autoplaying the video.

Comment: You can do it this way

$('.esg-youtube-frame').each(function(){
    var src = $(this).data('src');
    src += "&autoplay=1";
    console.log(src);
    $(this).data('src',src);
});

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I don't understand what you actually want to achieve, but:

For me the following works:

```
$('.esg-click-to-play-video').first().click()
```

See here:

Before:
[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Comment: This does not work

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$('.esg-youtube-frame').each(function(){ 
    var src = $(this).data('src'); 
    src += "&autoplay=1"; 
    $(this).data('src',src); 
});
```