# How to run the Div element when the page load is complete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an Html page containing multiple div, something like that :

```
<div id="div1">div1</div>
<div id="div2">div that contains youtube videos </div>
<div id="div3">div3</div>
```

I want to execute the #div2 after the page is loaded, is there any way to do that.

PS: I want to load the whole page firstly after that I want to load the #div2 ( and that because #div2 contains youtube videos which make the load very slow.

I find some code examples :

Comment: Do you use `iframe` tag to loading video?

Comment: yes I use iframe

Comment: are you passing the autoplay param? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7286526/8526705

Comment: unfortunately No, But i am not asking about play (autoplay) videos , what I am asking for is Loading the video from youtube

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could potentially use a script template as the default element, and then replace it on page load.

```js
$(window).on('load', function () {
  var $div2 = $('#div2');
  
  $div2.replaceWith( '<div id="div2">'+ $div2.html() +'</div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">div1</div>
<script type="text/html" id="div2">div that contains <b>youtube</b> videos </script>
<div id="div3">div3</div>
```

Comment: thank you , this solution worked for me...but with $( window ).load(function() { ... });

Comment: @IbtissamIbtissama `.load()`, when used with a callback function, is short hand for `on('load')`.  They are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Store URL of iframe in custom data attribute `data-src` and after page load insert it into `src` attribute of iframe.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#div2 iframe").attr("src", function(){
    return $(this).data("src")
  }).parent().show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">div1</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none">
  <iframe src="" data-src="http://youtube.com"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="div3">div3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it invisible when page load

```
<div id="div1" style="display:none">
  <p><em>Your Desired div will show after 5 second(s).</em></p>
</div>
```

Then make it visible after 5 secods on page loaded:

```
$(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#div1').show();
  },5000);
});
```

**Hope this will help you**

Comment: why are you redirecting to the homepage?

Comment: Dear it's will not redirect anywhre it's just show to your fixed div after 5 seconds

Comment: Are you sure that video in hidden div doesn't loaded?

Comment: your original answer had the script "redirecting to homepage". Calling `show()` won't invoke video playback as required.

Comment: No dear it's will loaded but not display on 5 seconds . If you want to load a full div or content after full page load then you have to call ajax .

Comment: I m sorry but I already tried this , it load the videos + its make the div invisible for 5s....I do not want to load the youtube videos till the whole page is loaded....I do not want to execute the #div2 , but thank you :D

Comment: Dude if you want to load youtube vedio after page load then you have to work with ajax. it's can work on fixed element after page load.