# Autoplay video embed

Tags: javascript, html

I have one issue about autoplay video in html. I just write a index.html file and embed a Youtube video into it. I know how to play video automatically by add "?autoplay=1" in link source but when I open this file the first time, my video dont autoplay. Then, I refresh page and it play automatically

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M_ueZ9E2g_c?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen style="margin-top: 30px;"></iframe>
```

So, my question is Why does it not play automatically in the first time and how to solve it? Thanks very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [YouTube Iframe embed auto play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281765/youtube-iframe-embed-auto-play)

Comment: Works for me: https://output.jsbin.com/niqewokowe

Comment: Works for me, too, even when I open it as `file:///`

Comment: works fine with `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M_ueZ9E2g_c?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: don't works for me. https://jsfiddle.net/qfvg15eL/

Comment: What Webbrowser do you use?

Comment: I'm using chrome

Comment: Just tested this in firefox and chrome without any problems..

Comment: **Related**: Disable Autoplay Videos in Chrome on Android. Android makes disabling autoplay videos simple. First, launch Chrome on your phone or tablet and go to Settings > Site Settings. Next, scroll down the menu and tap on Media and then Autoplay and toggle the switch off. [Link](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/disable-autoplay-videos-on-sites-in-google-chrome/)

Comment: @iLuvLogix I triying desktop chrome and doesn't working.

Comment: [autoplay policy change of chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)