# How to configure my html to play videos youtube?

Tags: html, eclipse

I'm a newbie in HTML ... I'm trying to do my best ;)
I want to add an youtube video, to do that I've added this piece of code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BLABLA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

it works ... but, the video never plays... loading loading ... and loading
I'm under eclipse, so I tried to play the video in the Web Browser editor.
I tried to play another video (without "embed" in the url, but a classical url) and same ... loading loading ...
I've filled the network connection in the Preferences to bypass my proxy

Maybe the youtube subscription blocks the video??

Another idea ?
Many thanks

Christelle

Comment: adding `?autoplay=1`. Try like this `<iframe width="560" height="315" src=" https://www.youtube.com/embed/[Video ID]I?&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: no :(. Can the subscription block the video?

Comment: I've tested with my own PC (without proxy) and it works ... :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to embed an autoplaying YouTube video in an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281765/how-to-embed-an-autoplaying-youtube-video-in-an-iframe)

Comment: Do you use a proxy for playing video? this is your problem can't play bcoz use a proxy?

Comment: no ... I've found ... in my company, we use ZScaler internet access ... :(

Comment: again ... I'm testing lot of things ... I tried to open under Eclipse a Web browser and launch a youtube video (not mine, another..) and it was blocked as long as accept or decline the subscription from youtube. I declined and then my video works under my web editor ... Is there a way to that under my hmtl code ?