# Trying to use a embedded youTube link for auto play in custom HTML

Tags: javascript, html, shopify

I am trying to implement a embedded youTube link to a custom Html page and setting it to autoplay but as I open my Homepage video doesn't play and only played when clicked .

```
<iframe width="1560" height="415" src="https://www.youtube.com/../?autoplay=1"
                            frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I want to make it responsive.

Comment: That's not what "responsive" means in web dev FYI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to embed an autoplaying YouTube video in an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281765/how-to-embed-an-autoplaying-youtube-video-in-an-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps or even works but have you tried something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(iframe).click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You said `https://www.youtube.com/../?autoplay=1`

Get rid of that slash before the question mark

I think it should be `https://www.youtube.com/viddata?autoplay=1` instead.

Maybe thats why its not playing

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the slash in the URL like Coder2195 said (`https://www.youtube.com/viddata?autoplay=1`). Also try to add this script to the HTML file:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  var videoElement = document.getElementById("videoElement");
  videoElement.click()
}
</script>
```

And make the iframe element have a custom id:

```
<iframe id="videoElement" width="1560" height="415" src="https://www.youtube.com/../?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```